# App crashes when starting activity to download new version of app

Tags: android, android-activity

When I start my application, I use the following functionality to start the DownloadNewVersion task:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    MyApplication MyApp;
    NavigationView navigationView;
    AdView mAdView;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     **startActivity(new Intent(this, updater.DownloadNewVersion.class));
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);**
```

But when I start my app, it simply crashes with the following error:

```
04-09 19:49:19.959 3484-3484/com.app.sipp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.app.sipp, PID: 3484 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.app.sipp/com.app.sipp.MainActivity}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.app.sipp/com.app.sipp.updater$DownloadNewVersion}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml? at
```

This is the class "Updater", where I would like to run DownloadNewVersion to download a new version of the app.

```
public class Updater extends AppCompatActivity {

    ProgressDialog bar;
    private static String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private int AppVersion = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView heading    = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.heading);
        Button   update_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);

        heading.setText("App Version: " + AppVersion);

        update_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                new DownloadNewVersion().execute();

            }
        });

    }

    class DownloadNewVersion extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,Boolean> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            bar = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            bar.setCancelable(false);

            bar.setMessage("Downloading...");

            bar.setIndeterminate(true);
            bar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            bar.show();

        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(progress);

            bar.setIndeterminate(false);
            bar.setMax(100);
            bar.setProgress(progress[0]);
            String msg = "";
            if(progress[0]>99){

                msg="Finishing... ";

            }else {

                msg="Downloading... "+progress[0]+"%";
            }
            bar.setMessage(msg);

        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            bar.dismiss();

            if(result){

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Update Done",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }else{

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error: Try Again",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            Boolean flag = false;

            try {


                URL url = new URL("http://androidpala.com/tutorial/app-debug.apk");

                HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                c.setRequestMethod("GET");
                c.setDoOutput(true);
                c.connect();


                String PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Download/";
                File file = new File(PATH);
                file.mkdirs();

                File outputFile = new File(file,"app-debug.apk");

                if(outputFile.exists()){
                    outputFile.delete();
                }

                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
                InputStream is = c.getInputStream();

                int total_size = 1431692;//size of apk

                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int len1 = 0;
                int per = 0;
                int downloaded=0;
                while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);
                    downloaded +=len1;
                    per = (int) (downloaded * 100 / total_size);
                    publishProgress(per);
                }
                fos.close();
                is.close();

                OpenNewVersion(PATH);

                flag = true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Update Error: " + e.getMessage());
                flag = false;
            }
            return flag;

        }

    }

    void OpenNewVersion(String location) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(location + "app-debug.apk")),
                "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you include a crash report?

Comment: Try calling `super.onCreate` before anything in your `MainActivity` though it would have been better if you also provided the crash logs

Comment: Where is your MainActivity.class layout file ? And why are you using all codes as you can use the library and download the apk in just using two line of code ?

Comment: Main its not complet but i need juste call updater

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to execute the following code:
`startActivity(new Intent(this, updater.DownloadNewVersion.class));`

This means you're telling your application to start a new activity, namely the activity "updater.DownloadNewVersion". However, your class `DownloadNewVersion` is an ASyncTask.

Your app is crashing with the following warning : `Unable to find explicit activity class {com.app.sipp/com.app.sipp.updater$DownloadNewVersion}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?` as it cannot find your Activity, both in your code and in your Manifest file as it is not actually an Activity.

If you're trying to open your Updater Activity, use the following instead:

`startActivity(new Intent(this, Updater.class));`